# best way to fix bad dates in a large dataset

Tags: python, pandas

My data set does not contain the 30th, when changed to CSV the 30th was changed to 3rd. I have two 3rd in each month. What is the best way to change the second 3rd to the 30th using Python?

https://ibb.co/g7XM2cC

Answer (score 1):

You can use `cumcount` to mark the second value and change it:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([['1/3/2010'], ['1/3/2010']], columns=['date']).astype('datetime64')
print(df)

condition = (df['date'].dt.day == 3) & (df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='date', freq='M')).cumcount() == 1)
subset = df.loc[condition, 'date']
df.loc[condition, 'date'] = pd.to_datetime({'year': subset.dt.year, 'month': subset.dt.month, 'day': 30})
print(df)
```

Output:

```
        date
0 2010-01-03
1 2010-01-03

        date
0 2010-01-03
1 2010-01-30
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I get an error when I run this in Jupyter Notebook -NameError: name 'subset' is not defined

Comment: I got it working, I needed to change the date to datetime format. However, it is changing the 1st 3 to 30 rather than the 2nd 3.

Comment: @RobE What happens when you run my sample code? Do you get the right output? If so, that suggests that there is something different about your data.

Comment: when I run your sample code I get the right output. I'm thinking my data may be off like you said. I'll check it over, thanks for the input- the code is appreciated!

Comment: @RobE I think I know why; there is actually a bug in my code if you have multiple years of data. I will modify it.

Comment: I tried the new code, it did nothing to the dates, not even change the first 3rd. What could be wrong with the data that would cause the cod not to work? should it start with a 30th? To you other point, yes I have many years of data, back to 1990.